# Electron JS MediaRecorder Codec problem on Safari

Tags: safari, electron, mediarecorder

I am recording video as Webm/H264 codec for cross platform. And also all datas are uploading as multipart to aws s3 storage as bytearray on record time. I need to re-encoding on mediarecorder dataavailable event as MP4. Because safari cannot play video with WebM. (i am using VideoJS for web player as well)

I've tried like below but not working.

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', async (event) => {
    const chunk = new Blob([event.data], { type: 'video/mp4' });
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(await chunk.arrayBuffer());
   
   //Multipart upload process....
});
```

So how can i re-encode blob or bytearray data to mp4? Do you have any idea?